# How do I find the my version Number of MS ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I know I am not running the most up-to-date version of ACT on my server. *(I tried to update it recently and it broke a bunch of things.)*

So I want to use a control that I have never used before and I need to look at the reference for the control to be sure I'm using it correctly. But I dont know the exact version I am running.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file and view the properties.  The version number there will tell you what version you are using.

Comment: I had to click the 'version' tab, but yes this worked.  Thanks much!